# Convert structure in another

Tags: javascript

i have this structure:

```
[
  [
    {
      "title": "something",
      "dataKey": "cod"
    },
    {
      "title": "something_2",
      "dataKey": "des"
    },
    {
      "title": "something_3",
      "dataKey": "orc"
    },
    {
      "title": "something_4",
      "dataKey": "orca"
    },
    {
      "title": "something_5",
      "dataKey": "arr"
    },
    {
      "title": "something_6",
      "dataKey": "por"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "VALUE_1",
      "dataKey": "cod"
    },
    {
      "title": "VALUE_2",
      "dataKey": "des"
    },
    {
      "title": "VALUE_3",
      "dataKey": "orc"
    },
    {
      "title": "VALUE_4",
      "dataKey": "orca"
    },
    {
      "title": "VALUE_5",
      "dataKey": "arr"
    },
    {
      "title": "VALUE_6",
      "dataKey": "por"
    }
  ]
]
```

It is necessary to transform this structure so that it is as follows:

```
[
  [
    { "cod": "something" },
    { "des": "something_2" },
    { "orc": "something_3" },
    { "orca": "something_4" },
    { "arr": "something_5" },
    { "por": "something_6" }
  ],
  [
    { "cod": "VALUE" },
    { "des": "VALUE_2" },
    { "orc": "VALUE_3" },
    { "orca": "VALUE_4" },
    { "arr": "VALUE_5" },
    { "por": "VALUE_6" }
  ]
]
```

I created this simple repeat structure to accomplish this conversion. However, by performing tests, I can sometimes print line by line, or, return [[object Object]]. I would like you to help me understand how to do this. I've already done a lot of research but I could not understand

```
var newData = temp1.map((item, i) => {
    temp1[i].map((subItem, j) => {
        ({[subItem.dataKey]: subItem.title});
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
let data = [
  [
    {
      title: 'something',
      dataKey: 'cod',
    },
    {
      title: 'something_2',
      dataKey: 'des',
    },
    {
      title: 'something_3',
      dataKey: 'orc',
    },
    {
      title: 'something_4',
      dataKey: 'orca',
    },
    {
      title: 'something_5',
      dataKey: 'arr',
    },
    {
      title: 'something_6',
      dataKey: 'por',
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      title: 'VALUE_1',
      dataKey: 'cod',
    },
    {
      title: 'VALUE_2',
      dataKey: 'des',
    },
    {
      title: 'VALUE_3',
      dataKey: 'orc',
    },
    {
      title: 'VALUE_4',
      dataKey: 'orca',
    },
    {
      title: 'VALUE_5',
      dataKey: 'arr',
    },
    {
      title: 'VALUE_6',
      dataKey: 'por',
    },
  ],
];

console.log(
  data.map(x => {
    return x.map(y => {
      let obj = {};
      obj[y.dataKey] = y.title;
      return obj;
    });
  })
);
```

**EDIT**

In the code you posted, you're just missing the returns.

SEE:

```
console.log(
temp1.map((item, i) => {
    return temp1[i].map((subItem, j) => {  // return here
        return ({[subItem.dataKey]: subItem.title}); // return here
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're actually really close, you just:

1. Forgot to *return* the result of the inner `map` (in the below, I do that by using the concise arrow function instead of a verbose one [one with a function body[ that you used), and
2. There's no need for `temp1[i]` when you *already* have `item`

So:

```
const newData = temp1.map(item =>
  item.map(subItem => ({[subItem.dataKey]: subItem.title}))
);
```

or with a verbose arrow function instead:

```
const newData = temp1.map(item => {
  return item.map(subItem => ({[subItem.dataKey]: subItem.title}))
//^^^^^^
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const temp1 = [
      [
        {
          "title": "something",
          "dataKey": "cod"
        },
        {
          "title": "something_2",
          "dataKey": "des"
        },
        {
          "title": "something_3",
          "dataKey": "orc"
        },
        {
          "title": "something_4",
          "dataKey": "orca"
        },
        {
          "title": "something_5",
          "dataKey": "arr"
        },
        {
          "title": "something_6",
          "dataKey": "por"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "title": "VALUE_1",
          "dataKey": "cod"
        },
        {
          "title": "VALUE_2",
          "dataKey": "des"
        },
        {
          "title": "VALUE_3",
          "dataKey": "orc"
        },
        {
          "title": "VALUE_4",
          "dataKey": "orca"
        },
        {
          "title": "VALUE_5",
          "dataKey": "arr"
        },
        {
          "title": "VALUE_6",
          "dataKey": "por"
        }
      ]
    ];

const newData = temp1.map(item =>
  item.map(subItem => ({[subItem.dataKey]: subItem.title}))
);
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: You explained very well, though the friend above answered first. But I give the same honors to you from an alternative point of view.